# Creating equally split buffers between points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, buffer, polygon-creation

I want to create buffers for every health facility, but they end up overlapping.

How can I create buffers that split equally between the distance of 2 health facilities?

Example of the result wanted in the screenshot:

[image: no overlaps buffers]

Comment: Similar topic on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/8g0wgj/mixed_voronoibuffer_polygons/, unfortunately with no answer, but with an interesting comment: *Have you tried using Clip on the Voronoi polygons with your specified Buffer as the clip layer?*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use "Voronoi Polygons", "Buffer" and "Clip" tools, respectively (or "Buffer" > "Voronoi Polygons" > "Clip").

**Step 1.** ["Voronoi Polygons"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#voronoi-polygons) (You should try different values for `Buffer region`, it depends on the buffer distance you used)

[image]

**Step 2.** ["Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer)

[image]

**Step 3.** ["Clip"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#clip) (use "Voronoi Polygons" for `Input layer`, "Buffers" for `Overlay layer`):

[image]

Comment: For more details regarding the *'Buffer region'*, please check the: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220894/what-does-buffer-mean-in-qgis-voronoi-dialog

Answer (score 12):

1. Buffer the points
2. Voronoi the points with "buffer region..:" 500 % (whatever percentage large enough to include the buffers)
3. Intersect buffers with voronois
4. Extract by location the intersections intersecting the points

[image]