# Limiting Voronoi polygons with circles

Tags: qgis, buffer, voronoi-thiessen, circle

Using the following:

- **Layer 1**: Voronoi polygons
- **Layer 2**: Circles buffer for each points, polygons

When I Cut/Intersect in QGIS, here is what I can get as results.
This is ALMOST what I want.
**The thing is I would rather limit the circles to adjacent ones instead of the Voronoi polygon itself**.

(See image below, red arrows demonstrate the issue, I want this portion to be associated to the other circle instead)

I hope it's clear.
Is there a way to do that?
I've been trying a lot of things without any success.

[image]

Comment: You want to clip *individual* Voronoi shapes with a limiting buffer, not make a single common buffer from all points. Usually this would need to be done inside a loop or with a SQL query.

Comment: Cercles and voronoi polygons do not seem to match. Normally, the lines delimiting voronoi polyons should match the point where two buffers meet. I suspect a projection issue (you used different projections for buffer and voronoi polygons). Can you share your exact workflow how you get the buffers and the voronoi polygons? Can you share all layers (at least a sample)?

Comment: Voronoi polygons seem to be wrong, see e.g. the line marked with the top red arrow: the line delimiting the two neighboring points should be perpendicular to the connection of these two points, but it is clearly not. So something went wrong when creating the voronoi polygons.

Comment: @Vince, i think you are right, but do you have an exemple how to do that in QGIS?

Comment: Found a solution, i updated the post! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Check this answer please: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/416199/29431

Answer (score -1):

I found a QGIS model that does exactly what I need.
See example of results.
I also added the link to the MODEL3 file, see below.
Hope it helps whoever needs to accomplish the same thing as me.

[Link to download](https://plugins.qgis.org/models/8/)

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question in the sense that someone else with the same problem does not get any useful information what caused the problem. It would be good to include that information

Comment: This Answer doesn't contain the answer, just the fact that you found an answer. The whole point behind the Question/Answer model is that others can benefit.

Comment: Ok I see, pretty new to this forum so I'm not sure what are all the rules when answering questions. But i feel it can help other people also as it really suits my need and what I was looking for :)